# Probability of right subtree size of node

Tags: probability

Q: given the group (1,...,n) we generate a random binary search tree.
Lets call S: the number of nodes in the right subtree of the node with value [1] .
Calculate P(S=k) for every k.

I understand that for [1] to have a right subtree with k nodes, 
we must add [k+2] to the BST before we add [1],
AND the nodes ([2], [3]..to [k+1]) to be added after [1].

I fail to see how I can calculate said probability,
I would very much appreciate a bit of direction.

Edit: let's take (1,...,10) for example and k=2:
For the {right size of subtree of [1]} to be 2, the order of numbers added to BST must be [4] - > [1] - > [2] [3] (the rest can go anywhere).

Comment: Is it possible to show an example random BST with values indicated (for some small n)?  This might clarify the meanings of the terms and help motivate solution approaches from reviewers.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.  You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.